# Python hangs over ssh

Tags: python, linux, ssh, freeze

I'm trying to a run a python script directly over ssh like this:

```
ssh hostname python_script
```

Unfortunately nothing happens after python starts, and in fact the python process that is created remotely stays "alive" even after I disconnect from SSH. The same thing happens if I try to start the python interpreter, but other commands work fine.

Comment: what does your python script do?

Comment: what does this python_script do? does it mess with any of the stdios? does it run without issue when executed locally?

Comment: It uses pyinotify to watch users logging in and out of the machine. It works fine locally and remotely (when run from Bash) but not when started directly by SSH, and neither does the Python interpreter shell. I don't touch the streams apart from writing to stdout.

Comment: If you want to watch for users logging in and out- why are you using inotify? why not syslog? have the machine send you a message when people login/out rather than running an agent on it over ssh...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try `ssh -t hostname python_script`. By default, `ssh` doesn't allocate a pseudo-tty to interact with when it's given a program to run (although it does if you just do `ssh hostname`); `-t` tells it to do so.

Answer (score 1):

ssh -t is a good suggestion.

You might also try sprinkling print statements/functions in your code, writing to some file in /var/tmp or whatever, to see what it's doing.

Another way of seeing what a process is doing is to use something like Linux' strace:
http://stromberg.dnsalias.org/~strombrg/debugging-with-syscall-tracers.html

EG: ssh remote.host.com 'strace -f -o /var/tmp/my_script.strace my_script'.  Then inspect /var/tmp/my_script.strace to see what it's stuck on.  Reading strace output isn't always simple, but at least it's interesting.  :)

Answer (score 0):

SSH isn't going to cause problems running a python script. In general the things to watch out for are environment variables changing and any expectation on standard input/output as these can cause symptoms similar to what you described. Running python directly will hang as python expects to be able to interact with stdin/stdout if not running a script.

An easy way to test that the basic environment is working is to create a test program (test.py) containing:

```
print "foo"
```

then

```
ssh hostname python test.py
```

you should get "foo" as a response.

Comment: That works but my script still doesn't output anything. Would inotify care if my program was started by a login shell?