# GitLab-CI: Run Python Script and Exit (VPS)

Tags: python, python-3.x, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I am trying to do a CI script on GitLab where it connects to my VPS, Git Pulls and then runs the python script and exits, while leaving my python script running 24/7 (until the next pipeline run/commit).

How do I do get it do make my python script run 24/7?

```
script:
    - 'apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y && apt-get install sshpass -y '
    - sshpass -p "password" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no root@host "cd repo/ && git pull && python3 main.py"
```

This is my current script, however, when `main.py` is run, the pipeline is left in limbo since the script is eternally running.

How do I make it so the pipeline script runs the script and exits, leaving it on `tmux` or something like that?

Answer (score 1):

Check first if this is a tty allocation issue, as [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11992595/6309).

```
ssh -t -o ...
    ^^
```

Also consider calling just one script (which does the `cd`, `git pull` and `python3`)

That way you can test the script locally (on 'host'), and then call it remotely (through `ssh`)

---

From the [OP Kevin A.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14543064/kevin-a) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74661343/gitlab-ci-run-python-script-and-exit-vps/74664765?noredirect=1#comment131788269_74664765):

> my code goes through a loop that reruns the code every 45mins or so, so the script is constantly running. It's a web scraper constantly updating a cloud database.
>
> The idea is to get GitLab CI to ignore waiting for the script to finish running, its just is to, stop previous script running, git pull and run the script again

Another approach would be to make the script scrap one-time (and exit), but call said script through a [GitLab scheduled pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html).
That way, no more freeze.

Comment: Ill try it. Is it worth the effort to go through the effort of making my program into a docker container? It's a web scraper so it would run on loop and I'm using GitLab so would that allow me to easily build and run it each time I have a new commit?

Comment: I've run it using `ssh -t -o...` but the GitLab CI seems to be waiting for the script to finish running, and not running the script then exiting (allowing the script to run indefinitely, until next push)

Comment: @KevinA. just for testing, if you replace the `python3` call by a simple `echo`, does it work? Or even a `python3` call like `python3 -c "print('test')"`

Comment: @KevinA. Try and replace your `main.py` with that one echo (to confirm it works), and then restore bit by bit `main.py` original content to understand what call/command is triggering the freeze.

Comment: My main.py leads to different files that run my code haha. But my code goes through a loop that reruns the code every 45mins or so, so the script is constantly running. It's a web scraper constantly updating a cloud database. The idea is to get GitLab CI to ignore waiting for the script to finish running, its just is to, stop previous script running, git pull and run the script again

Comment: @KevinA. "my code goes through a loop that reruns the code every 45mins": OK, that might be the issue then. It is best if the script itself does not loop, but is called at regular interval ([scheduled pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html)).

Comment: That seems like it could work. Does GitLab CI have any limitations for this, such as how many times I can run a pipeline? For example, I would want to run my script ~every 45mins.

Comment: Because if it takes 10mins for my scraper to run, and I run it every 45 mins, in less than 3 days I would use up all the free CI minutes for the month haha

Comment: @KevinA. Yes, you can use a [cron-like syntax](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/cron/).